# R code for reading tabular data files and plotting light curves of modeled stars

Tags: r

I am given a file named `profile1.data` that looks like this:

```
  zone luminosity
1    1   1359.019
2    2   1359.030
3    3   1359.009
4    4   1358.988
5    5   1358.969
6    6   1358.951
```

There are *thousands* of profiles in my working directory (named `profileNUMBER.data`). Every one of them has a unique value called a `phase` that I have beforehand (meaning there is the same number of phase values as there are profiles) and every one of them has 300 rows (thus 300 zones).

What I am doing with this data is plotting luminosity vs phase *for each zone*. For example, to create a luminosity vs phase plot of the first zone, I grab the luminosity value from every  profile in the directory at zone 1. This is my first plot. Then I do the same for the other 299 zones. At the moment, I am accomplishing this through for loops in R.

```
for (zone_num in 1:300) { 

    luminosities <- c()

   for (prof_num in prof.idx$prof_num) { 
     
    prof.path <- file.path(cwd,log.directory.after.FA, paste0('profile', prof_num, '.data'))
    if (!file.exists(prof.path)) next 
    #print(prof.path)
    DF.profile <- read.table(prof.path, header=1, skip=5) 
      
      luminosity <- DF.profile$luminosity[zone_num]
      luminosities <- c(luminosities, luminosity)
      
   }
    
    png(file.path(plot.set.dir, paste("Zone",zone_num,"Light_Curve.png",sep="_")), width = 750, height = 600)
    par(mar=c(5,5,4,1)+.1)
    plot(x=phases, y=luminosities, main=paste(sets[set],"Zone",zone_num ,"Light Curve",sep=" "), pch=3, col="purple",
         xlab=expression("Phase"), ylab=expression("Luminosity " (L/L['\u0298'])), cex.main=2.0, cex.lab=1.50, ceb.axis=1.80)
    dev.off()

  }
```

This is not the entire code and there are some variables that you do not see the definition of, but the point is for you to see how I structured the solution using for loops. I'm particularly interested in how to use R's unique vectorized functions to speed this up.

**Edit 1**
Link to profile folders:

Comment: vectorized functions are mostly for math not creating hundreds of plots....

Comment: @minem Ok, would there still be anyway this can be improved to expedite plot creation?

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code after an answer has been posted. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provided data or explanation what's `prof.idx$prof_num` I am guessing that's vector of file names (part of filename).
This could work:

```
prof_num <- prof.idx$prof_num # vector of names? if so, should work
prof.path <- file.path(cwd,log.directory.after.FA, paste0('profile', prof_num, '.data')) # vectorized function
pathList <- prof.path[file.exists(prof.path)] # take those who exists

# read data list
dataList <- lapply(pathList, function(x) {
  DF.profile <- read.table(x, header=1, skip=5)
  # DF.profile
  DF.profile$luminosity
})

# plots:
for (zone_num in 1:300) {
  luminosities <- sapply(dataList, function(v) v[zone_num])
  png(file.path(plot.set.dir, paste("Zone",zone_num,"Light_Curve.png",sep="_")), width = 750, height = 600)
  par(mar=c(5,5,4,1)+.1)
  plot(x=phases, y=luminosities, main=paste(sets[set],"Zone",zone_num ,"Light Curve",sep=" "), pch=3, col="purple",
       xlab=expression("Phase"), ylab=expression("Luminosity " (L/L['\u0298'])), cex.main=2.0, cex.lab=1.50, ceb.axis=1.80)
  dev.off()
}
```

As I don't have the data to test I am not 100% sure that this will fork...
But from your code it seems that the biggest problem is that you are repeatedly reading the same files into R. This should be done once separately.

Comment: As soon as it completes zipping, I'll send all the data as well as my entire code. Yes, `prof.idx` is a data frame read from a file in the directory that lists the number of profiles, and `prof.idx$prof_num` is the vector of file names.

Comment: @Woj this doesn't work?

Comment: @Woj https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: See edit 1 in post.

Comment: @Woj your full code is too convoluted for me to dig into and I wont download any data, but I believe you will be able to incorporate this into your code

Comment: Please consider waiting with an answer until the question has been fixed. Now we can't allow the edit in the question because the answer has come in already, but the proper action would've been to close the question and leave a comment instead of answering it. There are *plenty* of clear, on-topic questions on this site that could use your experience where you won't have to guess at the intentions.